# What should I know to change the programming language?

Tags: stack, migration, programming-languages

what have I to be aware of to change the language from Angular to Java?

1. What to do to make it smoother in terms of learning?
2. How to find the first job on the new technology?
3. Any other recommendations will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First of all Angular is not a language, it's a framework. If you're familiar with Typescript than you set the first step to learn Java. You have to be clear what do you want to archive. With Angular you build a "single-page" application and with Java you could build the backend for your "single-page" application.
Think of a small project and combine Angular with Java. In my opinion it's much easier to learn by practice instead solely by a book.